# Not being able to find an edge case in question "Process Tasks Using Servers" asked in leetcode weekly contest 243

Tags: python-3.x, heap

[link to the question] (https://leetcode.com/problems/process-tasks-using-servers/). The problem statement is clearly written in the provided link.
I've highlighted a difference between my result and the expected result.

I'm not able to figure out which edge case or condition I've missed?

If the problem statement is still unclear then please do let me know.

**Update**: The updated solution is in the comment section.

```
import heapq
class Solution:
    def assignTasks(self, servers: List[int], tasks: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        serverPriority = [(name, index) for index, name in enumerate(servers)]
        
        # this sorts the server based on the priority order specified in the problem statement.
        serverPriority.sort()
         
        """
         A new ID is given to the server after sorting, 
         which is basically the index number of the servers 
         in **serverPriority** list.
       """
        serverId = [i for i in range(len(servers))]
        heapq.heapify(serverId)
        
        res = [-1] * len(tasks)
        

        runningServers = []
        heapq.heapify(runningServers)
        
        currTime = 0
        for j in range(len(tasks)):
            # if no servers are running then selects a server from the pool of available servers.
            if len(runningServers) == 0:
                ID = heapq.heappop(serverId)
                res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]
                
                heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
            else:
                """
                 if some servers are running then it checks whether any server
                 is going to stop execution at **currentTime**, or before that 
                 and then selects that server for running another task.
                """
                if currTime >= runningServers[0][0]:
                    time, ID = heapq.heappop(runningServers)
                    res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]
                    
                    heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
                else:
                    """
                     case when none of the running server can be chosen. 
                     so it chooses one from the pool.
                    """
                    if len(serverId) > 0:
                        ID = heapq.heappop(serverId)
                        res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]
                        
                        heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
                    else:
                        """
                        If no servers are available in pool then it has to wait 
                         for one of the running server to stop.
                        """
                        time, ID = heapq.heappop(runningServers)
                        currTime = time
                        res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]
                        
                        heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
            currTime += 1
            
        return res
```

Passed test cases:

1. servers = [3,3,2], tasks = [1,2,3,2,1,2]

- expected: [2,2,0,2,1,2]

2. servers = [5,1,4,3,2], tasks = [2,1,2,4,5,2,1]

- expected: [1,4,1,4,1,3,2]

Failed test case:

1. servers = [338,890,301,532,284,930,426,616,919,267,571,140,716,859,980,469,628,490,195,664,925,652,503,301,917,563,82,947,910,451,366,190,253,516,503,721,889,964,506,914,986,718,520,328,341,765,922,139,911,578,86,435,824,321,942,215,147,985,619,865]

tasks =[773,537,46,317,233,34,712,625,336,221,145,227,194,693,981,861,317,308,400,2,391,12,626,265,710,792,620,416,267,611,875,361,494,128,133,157,638,632,2,158,428,284,847,431,94,782,888,44,117,489,222,932,494,948,405,44,185,587,738,164,356,783,276,547,605,609,930,847,39,579,768,59,976,790,612,196,865,149,975,28,653,417,539,131,220,325,252,160,761,226,629,317,185,42,713,142,130,695,944,40,700,122,992,33,30,136,773,124,203,384,910,214,536,767,859,478,96,172,398,146,713,80,235,176,876,983,363,646,166,928,232,699,504,612,918,406,42,931,647,795,139,933,746,51,63,359,303,752,799,836,50,854,161,87,346,507,468,651,32,717,279,139,851,178,934,233,876,797,701,505,878,731,468,884,87,921,782,788,803,994,67,905,309,2,85,200,368,672,995,128,734,157,157,814,327,31,556,394,47,53,755,721,159,843]

expected: [26,50,47,11,56,31,18,55,32,9,4,2,23,53,43,0,44,30,6,51,29,51,15,17,22,34,38,33,42,3,25,10,49,51,7,58,16,21,19,31,19,12,41,35,45,52,13,59,47,36,1,28,48,39,24,8,46,20,5,54,27,37,14,57,40,59,8,45,4,51,47,7,58,4,31,23,54,7,9,56,2,46,56,1,17,42,11,30,12,44,14,32,7,10,23,1,29,27,6,10,33,24,19,10,35,30,35,10,17,49,50,36,29,1,48,44,7,11,24,57,42,30,10,55,3,20,38,15,7,46,32,21,40,16,59,30,53,17,18,22,51,11,53,36,57,26,5,**36,56**,55,31,34,57,7,52,37,31,10,0,51,41,2,32,25,0,7,49,47,13,14,24,57,28,4,45,43,39,38,8,2,44,45,29,25,25,12,54,5,44,30,27,23,26,7,33,58,41,25,52,40,58,9,52,40]

my result: [26,50,47,11,56,31,18,55,32,9,4,2,23,53,43,0,44,30,6,51,29,51,15,17,22,34,38,33,42,3,25,10,49,51,7,58,16,21,19,31,19,12,41,35,45,52,13,59,47,36,1,28,48,39,24,8,46,20,5,54,27,37,14,57,40,59,8,45,4,51,47,7,58,4,31,23,54,7,9,56,2,46,56,1,17,42,11,30,12,44,14,32,7,10,23,1,29,27,6,10,33,24,19,10,35,30,35,10,17,49,50,36,29,1,48,44,7,11,24,57,42,30,10,55,3,20,38,15,7,46,32,21,40,16,59,30,53,17,18,22,51,11,53,36,57,26,5,**56,36**,55,31,34,57,7,52,37,31,10,0,51,41,2,32,25,0,7,49,47,13,14,24,57,28,4,45,43,39,38,8,2,44,45,29,25,25,12,54,5,44,30,27,23,26,7,33,58,41,25,52,40,58,9,52,40]

Comment: Without reviewing your code yet, I notice that the discrepancy is in adjoining entries and that a quick scan of the problem shows the following requirements already highlighted "**To process task j, you assign it to the server with the smallest weight that is free, and in case of a tie, choose the server with the smallest index.**" Is it possible these servers are free, but you have chosen the higher index one to allocate first?

Comment: Similarly, have you accounted for "**If multiple tasks need to be assigned, assign them in order of increasing index.**"?

Comment: When you ask a question you should at least answer to the comments made... Total silence is not motivating anyone to look into your question.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I was assigning a server to a new task based on their finish time. So, let's say if running servers are s1, s2, s3 and assume that first s3 got free and then s2, so for task4 the algorithm would choose s3 instead of s2. **(assuming server priority order is: s1 > s2 > s3)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A point to remember**: Servers present inside **runningServers** heap have higher priority than the servers that are present in the pool **serverId** waiting for some task.

**Now, assume that we have 3 servers s1, s2, s3 having priority order **s1 > s2 > s3**, and 4 tasks t1, t2, t3, t4 with arrival time in increasing order.
Also, assume that when we were about to allocate a server for t4, then by that time s2 and s3 got free.**

Now, ideally, we should choose server s2 for task t4 but the above-given algorithm is going to choose s3 for t4 because it's maintaining a min-heap property on the finish time of the servers. So it's important to first free all the servers that have **finish time <= currTime**, and then choose a new server for t4 from the pool.

**Now, what would happen if no server can be chosen from runningServer and we don't even have any server available in the pool serverId?**

**solution**: We'll have to wait for some time for one of the servers to get free. let's say a server is going to get free at **time = x ms**, and it is also possible that there are multiple servers that are going to get free at **time = x ms.**

So, the final solution for the problem statement is:

```
serverPriority = [(name, index) for index, name in enumerate(servers)]
        
        serverPriority.sort()

        serverId = [i for i in range(len(servers))]
        heapq.heapify(serverId)
        
        res = [-1] * len(tasks)
        
        runningServers = []
        heapq.heapify(runningServers)
        
        currTime = 0
        j = 0
        while j < len(tasks):
            currTime = max(currTime, j)
            
            if len(runningServers) == 0:
                ID = heapq.heappop(serverId)
                res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]
                
                heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
            else:
                # Here, we are first freeing up the servers
                while len(runningServers) > 0 and currTime >= runningServers[0][0]:
                    time, ID = heapq.heappop(runningServers)
                    heapq.heappush(serverId, ID)
            
                if len(serverId) > 0:
                    ID = heapq.heappop(serverId)
                    res[j] = serverPriority[ID][1]

                    heapq.heappush(runningServers, (currTime + tasks[j], ID))
                else:
                    """
                     here, we are keeping record of the server 
                     with earliest finish time.
                    """
                    time = runningServers[0][0]
                    currTime = time
                    j -= 1
            
            j += 1
            
        return res
```